# TabControl.Items.Remove(TabItem) does not free memory used by TabItem

Tags: .net, wpf, memory, wpf-controls

I am having a WPF application where when I close a `TabItem` from `TabControl` using `TabControl.Items.Remove(TabItem)` does not free memory used by ***TabItem***. It just makes ***TabItem*** invisible and ***TabItem*** object still remains in the memory. Is there any way to remove this ***TabItem*** object from memory ?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have event handlers on the TabItem?

Comment: I have got a UserControl(TextBoxes+Grids+Graphs+events on these) as a content in this TabItem and on this TabiItem there is one close button(CloseImage+click event).

Comment: What do you mean "TabItem remains in memory". How have you verified that?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know all eventhandlers must be 'detached', also you should release all bindings on your tabItem.

Also If I am not mistaken CommandBindings, KeyGestures can also cause the leak.

Try using CLR Profiler. It has saved me a lot of hours many times, though I haven't used it with WPF. But I'm pretty sure it can handle it.

Comment: CLR Profiler: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A362781C-3870-43BE-8926-862B40AA0CD0&displaylang=en

Comment: It can handle it. It can at times be pretty hardwork getting the right granularity however. I recommend using it with SOS/WinDbg to get the dump after you've done the repro rather running under the profiler, which can completely kill performance.

Comment: Another thing that can be done is to call GC.Collect after removing all event handlers etc, and see if the object is collected (just for debug purposes, of course) if it IS collected, you have no leaks, if not - you still haven't freed something

Answer (score 1):

You need to cut out an object from its parent completely for it to be garbage collected. That means also the events (-= blah).

Even that done, the object might still be in memory until the next sweep of the GC.

You can force a call of the GC but it's not recommended.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.aspx

Comment: I have got a UserControl(TextBoxes+Grids+Graphs+events on these) as a TabItem.Content and on this TabiItem there is one close button(CloseImage+click event). So which event(s) am I supposed to cut (TabItem.Content's events OR Click event put on close button)?

Comment: I believe the click ones and remove tab item.