# User Control not being finalized when removed from a tab control

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection

I have implemented a WPF `UserControl`.
This implementation includes the destructor.

If I make this control part of a window, and then destroy this window, and then force garbage collection(GC.Collect()), the destructor is called.

If I add this control to a `TabItem`, which is in turn added to a `TabControl`, and later remove this `TabItem` from the `TabControl`, and then force garbage collection(GC.Collect()), the destructor is not called.

Clarification:

Here is the code that adds the tab item:

```
            TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
            tabItem.Header = "User";
            UserControl1 userControl1 = new UserControl1();
            tabItem.Content = userControl1;
            userControl1.Width = Double.NaN;
            userControl1.Height = Double.NaN;
            userControl1.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            userControl1.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
            tc1.Items.Add(tabItem);
```

And here is the code to remove it:

```
            TabItem item = tc1.SelectedItem as TabItem;
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.Content = null;
                tc1.Items.Remove(item);
            }
```

Given that there should no longer be any references to either TabItem or UserControl1, I would expect the destructor to be called for UserControl1.

This is obviously not the case, so my next question is why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TabControl.Items.Remove(TabItem) does not free memory used by TabItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167943/tabcontrol-items-removetabitem-does-not-free-memory-used-by-tabitem)

Comment: Better describe 'force garbage collection' because that could mean several things. Use C# to avoid confusion.

Comment: Removing controls from a container does *not* cause them to be destroyed. The idea is that you might want to remove a control from one container and add it immediately to another container. Therefore, you need to manually handle destroying controls that you no longer need after removing them from a container.

Comment: If you wrote any destructors (`~ClassName(){}`) then do post them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF C# DataBinding List Finalization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528055/wpf-c-sharp-databinding-list-finalization)

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on or use destructors unless your class owns an unmanaged resource.

In your example, something, like event subscriber, may be holding a reference to the TabItem, preventing it from garbage collecting.

Comment: I have added example code above. I have added no event handlers, but it still seems that there is a lurking reference.