# WPF C# DataBinding List Finalization

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have implemented a user control that contains a ListBox that is bound to a List:

```
listBox1.ItemsSource = list;
```

I have implemented a method that removes the (only) reference to the list:

```
listBox1.ItemsSource = null;
```

Having called this method, I force garbage collection:

```
GC.Collect();
```

The destructor of my list class is not being called. There is obviously some hidden reference to the list.

Any explanation of this behavior would be gratefully received.

Comment: Have you tried `Gc.Colect(); Gc.WaitFor(); Gc.Collect();` ?

Comment: Are you wanting to remove the ItemSource's reference to the list, or do you want the ListBox to be empty?

Comment: I want to remove the reference

Comment: Are you seeing the change in listBox1 after you set the ItemsSource to null?

Comment: It is possible that WPF keeps some references, but for a better picture you would have to post more complete code. What is list, how quickly after `= null` do you call `Collect()` ?

Answer (score 1):

*list* is not null, so it's still alive.

```
list = null;
```

Comment: list is passed as a parameter that is no longer in scope after the assignment to ItemsSource

Comment: @user2187743 - But someone reading the question doesn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to derive the list class from ObservableCollection(or something that implements INotifyCollectionChanged) rather than List.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense in the context of the question.